# Matching picture javascript basic puzzle game

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making a simple javascript game and I'm a beginner and now I'm stuck. I have to create 5 arrays to store src image. Here is my code:

```js
var imagesPart1 = [
  "funny-cat1_part1x1.jpg",
  "monkey_part1x1.jpg",
  "panda_swap_part1x1.jpg"
];
var imagesPart2 = [
  "funny-cat1_part2x1.jpg",
  "monkey_part2x1.jpg",
  "panda_swap_part2x1.jpg"
];
var imagesPart3 = [
  "funny-cat1_part3x1.jpg",
  "monkey_part3x1.jpg",
  "panda_swap_part3x1.jpg"
];
var imagesPart4 = [
  "funny-cat1_part4x1.jpg",
  "monkey_part4x1.jpg",
  "panda_swap_part4x1.jpg"
];
var imagesPart5 = [
  "funny-cat1_part5x1.jpg",
  "monkey_part5x1.jpg",
  "panda_swap_part5x1.jpg"
];

function imageSwitch(id, arr) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  var counter = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));

  function nextPic() {
    counter += 1;
    if (counter > arr.length - 1) {
      counter = 0;
    }
    element.src = "./img/" + arr[counter];
  }
  element.addEventListener('click', nextPic);

  counter -= 1;



  nextPic();
}
imageSwitch("one", imagesPart1);
imageSwitch("two", imagesPart2);
imageSwitch("three", imagesPart3);
imageSwitch("four", imagesPart4);
imageSwitch("five", imagesPart5);
```

```css
div {
  width: 800px;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <img id="one" src="./img/funny-cat1_part1x1.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="two" src="./img/funny-cat1_part2x1.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="three" src="./img/funny-cat1_part3x1.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="four" src="./img/funny-cat1_part4x1.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="five" src="./img/funny-cat1_part5x1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```

Now I want if 5 parts making a complete image it will alert something or give a box shadow like this but I can't figure out how to get the ideal to do this.
[image: complete image]
and here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncongtrung1610/gwnev6y0/14/).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restructure your code a bit:

```js
// switch this to a 2d array
const imageParts = [
    [
        "https://i.ibb.co/4FrYJR3/funny-cat1-part1x1.jpg",
        "https://i.ibb.co/D9TLmt1/monkey-part1x1.jpg",
        "https://i.ibb.co/V2BXPVH/panda-swap-part1x1.jpg",
    ],
    [
        "https://i.ibb.co/CQyGWQq/funny-cat1-part2x1.jpg",
        "https://i.ibb.co/BgT0mNN/monkey-part2x1.jpg",
        "https://i.ibb.co/P6CGThy/panda-swap-part2x1.jpg",
    ],
    [
        "https://i.ibb.co/k07vFCb/funny-cat1-part3x1.jpg",
        "https://i.ibb.co/dbx5zcc/monkey-part3x1.jpg",
        "https://i.ibb.co/FK3h9Zd/panda-swap-part3x1.jpg",
    ],
    [
        "https://i.ibb.co/Vm5ZJ0g/funny-cat1-part4x1.jpg",
        "https://i.ibb.co/10hDp8c/monkey-part4x1.jpg",
        "https://i.ibb.co/HXWrzjs/panda-swap-part4x1.jpg",
    ],
    [
        "https://i.ibb.co/x8zQPWW/funny-cat1-part5x1.jpg",
        "https://i.ibb.co/2KKwwzG/monkey-part5x1.jpg",
        "https://i.ibb.co/N9vgw6y/panda-swap-part5x1.jpg",
    ],
];

// store ids in an array
const ids = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

// store counters in an array
const counters = new Array(ids.length).fill(0);

// helper function to check if every element in an array is equal
function checkAllSame(arr) {
  if (arr.length <= 1) {
    return true;
  }
  const first = arr[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i ++) {
    if (arr[i] !== first) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
} 

// loop through the element ids
for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i ++) {
  // get the current element
  const ele = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
  // get the current image parts
  const parts = imageParts[i];
  // initialize the counter to a random value
  let counter = Math.floor(Math.random() * parts.length);
  // update the counters array
  counters[i] = counter;
  // update the element
  ele.src = parts[counter];
  ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // on click increment the counter and use % to wrap around
    counter = (counter + 1) % parts.length;
    // update the element
    ele.src = parts[counter];
    // update the counters array
    counters[i] = counter;
    // if all the counters are the same, then it's a match
    if (checkAllSame(counters)) {
      // or whatever else you want to do
      // setTimeout of 0 lets the image load before the alert pops up
      setTimeout(function() {alert("you did it!")}, 0);
    }
  });
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkpn1qyf/3/).

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new function `setImage(arr, counter)` that includes your line `element.src = "./img/" + arr[counter];`, but also does something other things:

- It should store the index in a global variable, one that contains the index for all your images.
- It should check to see if those are all the same
- It should execute whatever visual feedback you want to see based on the check.

You have one roadblock which is that the array you pass to `imageSwitch` doesn't have an identifier of any kind ... you might want to put all your imageParts into an array (ah, I see another answer suggests this as well) and pass an index. Or perhaps an object where the keys are your ids, like:

```
{
  one: [...],
  two: [...],
  ...
}
```